# How do I start a new game as Luigi?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy

I've come back to Super Mario Galaxy after a few years and want to play from the beginning as Luigi. I have an existing save file that has Luigi unlocked by collecting 120 stars as Mario, but Luigi has already collected 16 stars on that file.

Is there a way to start a fresh save file as Luigi or restart Luigi's progress on an existing save file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to create a new save with 0 stars with Luigi is to first collect 120 stars with Mario.

There is no way to create a new savegame  with 120 stars already collected for Mario and 0 stars for Luigi except for copying an existing savegame that is exactly at that point in the game.

The game does not allow for you to remove already collected stars in a savegame.

Comment: Copying a save where Luigi has 0 stars is a good idea for the future.